# xcode uitest picker only moving one position

Tags: xcode, uipickerview, xcode-ui-testing

While working in Xcode Version 8.0 beta 5 (8S193k), I am trying to use the the following line to adjust the picker with four 'spinners'. (The indexes are correct as I have two other single pickers on the same page.)

```
    let pickCD     = app.pickerWheels.element(boundBy: 2)
    let pickCB     = app.pickerWheels.element(boundBy: 3)
    let pickSD     = app.pickerWheels.element(boundBy: 4)
    let pickSB     = app.pickerWheels.element(boundBy: 5)

    pickCD.adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "None")
    pickCB.adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "1")
    pickSD.adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "1")
    pickSB.adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "None")
```

The issue is that the pickers are only moving one position (in the direction of the desired value.  For example, if the first spinner has values 'None', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' and the current position is '3'.  When I run the test the spinner will only move to the value '2' and not to 'None'.

The other two spinners are working correctly and will move through over 200 elements to select the correct label using the same commands.

Thoughts?

Comment: Created Apple Bug Reporter item #27818469